# Need help identifying this plant

Tags: species-identification, botany

I found this guy growing in my compost, but have no clue, what it could be.

Any expert here who want to take a guess?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is your location?  And when was the photo taken?  You are almost certainly looking at something in the genus *Persicaria* and the family Polygnonaceae.  The clue is the ochrea, which is the papery sheath wrapping around the stem at the base of the leaves.

Comment: @BryanHanson This was taken in Hamburg, Germany a few hours ago

Comment: Alright someone familiar with European species in this genus will have to answer.  US species I am familiar with would not bloom until late summer.

Comment: If it is from a compost it couldn't it be from anywhere, since anything could have ended up in there?